# HTTP 401 auth error while logged in with gcloud auth

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-storage, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

try to get a blob from google cloud storage like this:

```
from gcloud import storage

gcs_client = storage.Client()
gcs_bucket = gcs_client.get_bucket('mybucketname')
gcs_blob = gcs_bucket.blob(path)
gcs_blob.download_to_file(somefileobject)
```

Pretty straightforward, however I get this error message:

> Unauthorized: 401 Login Required (GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o/path-to-file?projection=noAcl)

I'm logged in via cli (gcloud auth) and I've tried with a service account too with the same results.

gcloud config list output:

```
[compute]
region = europe-west1
zone = europe-west1-b
[core]
account = myemail@address.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = right-project-name
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does `gsutil ls gs://mybucketname/path/somefileobject` work for you?

Comment: Yep, gsutil works fine at the same time :(

Comment: Can you report what the value of `gcs_client.connection.credentials` is? I'd also recommend checking out the access token on that credentials object and then checking the scopes via: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}. Also what version of `gcloud`?